Can we interpret the null of the Mann–Whitney U test, i.e. $P(x_i > y_j) = P(y_j > x_i)$, as equivalent to $F = G$ (where $F$ and $G$ are ECDFs)?
Introduction.

Let's consider a sample of $n$ observations $\{x_i\} = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n\}$ from a population $X$ and a sample of $m$ observations $\{y_j\} = \{y_1, y_2, \ldots y_m\}$ from a population $Y$.

Let's consider the Mann–Whitney $\displaystyle U$ test (also called Wilcoxon rank-sum test), and its null and alternative hypotheses:

$H_0$: $P(x_i > y_j) = P(y_j > x_i) = \frac{1}{2}$ $\quad$ $\bigl($
i.e. "stochastic equality between $x$ and $y$" $\bigl)$
$H_A$: $P(x_i > y_j) \neq P(y_j > x_i)$ $\;$ $\bigl($ i.e. "$x$ will be
stochastically larger/smaller than $y$" $\bigl)$


Let's consider the Mann & Whitney (1947) paper:




Introduction. Let $x$ and $y$ be two random variables having continuous cumulative distribution functions $F$ and $G$ respectively.
The variable $x$ will be called stochastically smaller than $y$ if
$F(a) > G(a)$ for every $a$. We wish to test the hypothesis $F = G$
against the alternative that $x$ is stochastically smaller than $y$.


Question.

Can we interpret $H_0$: $P(x_i > y_j) = P(y_j > x_i) = \frac{1}{2}$  as equivalent to $F = G$?
$\bigl($Alternatively, can we interpret $H_A$: $P(x_i > y_j) \neq P(y_j > x_i)$  as equivalent to $F > or < G$?$\bigl)$
If Yes, the null $P(x_i > y_j) = P(y_j > x_i) = \frac{1}{2}$ would correspond to see the ECDFs points lying on the 45 degree diagonal of the p-p plot, since $F = G$.



If the two distributions are identical, then of course the p-value will be close to 1, as your own answer illustrates.
But the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney (WMW) test is only a test on stochastic dominance, not on distribution equality. The following implements an example from this answer to a similar question, based on two very different distributions for which WMW has a p value close to 1 but Kolmogorov-Smirnov is highly significant:
set.seed(20240906)
A <- rnorm(10000,0,1)
B1 <- rnorm(5000,-5,1)
B2 <- rnorm(5000,5,1)
B <- c(B1,B2)
wilcox.test(A,B)$p.value
# [1] 0.992639
ks.test(A,B)$p.value
# [1] 0

The following illustrates these distributions:

You certainly can not use an "insignificant" WMW test p-value on to infer that two distributions are (close to) the same.
Code for plot:
plot(density(B),bty="n",ylim=c(0,0.4),main="",xlab="Value")
lines(density(A),col="red")
legend("topleft", "A, red\nB, black",bty="n")


Thanks, Yes, in this case $P(X>Y)=P(X<Y)$... I was just trying to connect this concept to the  stuff of the Mann–Whitney (1947) paper. In particular, I was trying to understand if there was a connection to $F=G$, and if there was a visual way to understand $P(X>Y)=P(X<Y)$. This would help, indeed, to understand for which reason people use that test... I mean, I have seen that stochastic dominance is related to there relative "position" between CDFs (at least this is what I remember from an answer of @Whuber here on CV)

Mann and Whitney conflated the assumption of exchangeability under H0 with what sort of thing  the hypothesis test actually tests. Many authors followed suit. I explained this issue briefly in a comment previously. You require exchangeability under h0 but the test is NOT sensitive to general differences in distribution. It's just like assuming normal under H0 for a t test. That doesn't  make it a test of normality

Thanks.. with "conflate", do you mean "combine/merge" or "confuse"?... There are two meanings (at least) for that word in English. If you mean "confuse", then the mystery is solved, and my question is then cleared.
